# RegEx exclude sub-group text from being included in a parent sub-group

Tags: regex

For the sake of this question, I'll include a basic example of what I'm trying to do. I have been looking for a method using regex which would allow me to have an input such as this:

```
<a>$4<br>.00</a>
```

To match this in one sub-group `4.00`

I have tried numerous methods, all being around the lines of:

```
<a>\$([0-9]+<br>\.[0-9]+)</a>
or
<a>\$([0-9]+(?:<br>)\.[0-9]+)</a>
            ^-- Excludes <br> from being placed in a match group, but it does not
                exclude <br> from its parent match group, so we still get 4<br>.00
```

Both of the methods above match `4<br>.00`

My question is: Are there any other Regex operators that allow me to exclude certain sub-expressions from their parent sub-expressions? (Match `4<br>.00` but exclude `<br>` giving `4.00` in 1 sub-group)

Comment: Subgroup matches are always continuous. You can't exclude parts within a single match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to switch to using lxml. Even for minimal HTML parsing needs, lxml did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a replace function in whatever language that is?  Something along the lines of:

s.replaceAll( "<.+>", "" )

So that would replace all the tags in your string with the empty string and leave you with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, you don't have to really do it in one step. you can break it up into steps. Eg: Get the text from  to  and save to variable using `/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/`. then replace the tags

```
>>> import re
>>> s="<a>$4<br>.00</a>"
>>> re.sub("<a>(.*?)<\/a>","\\1",s)
'$4<br>.00'
>>> var=re.sub("<a>(.*?)<\/a>","\\1",s)
>>> re.sub("<.*?>","",var)
'$4.00'
```

Comment: This is the problem I'm trying to work around. I could just as well have the two strings returned as 2 sub-groups and concatenate them, but I need to be able to match using only 1 expression, as well as having 4.00 returned as 1 sub-group (ignoring the <br> in between).