# Regex positive lookahead

Tags: regex, perl, posix, regex-lookarounds

Why is this positive lookahead not matching the text in bold ? (not . and not ->)

```
[_a-z0-9]+(?=\.|->)[_a-z0-9]+
```

> **hints6**.**ai_flags**       = 0; // comment hints.ai_flags
>   **hints6**.**ai_family**        = AF_UNSPEC;
>   int newsocket = socket(**result**->**ai_family**, **result**->**ai_socktype**, **result**->**ai_protocol**);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, you need to escape the `.` (`.` matches 'anything', you want `\.` to match ".") [weird - someone edited the question to fix that]

second, a lookahead looks ahead - it doesn't consume anything.  so, even if you escape the `.`, `[_a-z0-9]+(?=\.|->)` is only *consuming* "hints6" (and then, looking ahead, confirming that the *next* character will be ".").  after that, `[_a-z0-9]+` fails to match the ".".

i don't really understand what you are trying to do.  as far as i can see, `[_a-z0-9]+(?:\.|->)[_a-z0-9]+` would do what you want, without any lookahead (`(?:...)` is a grouping that doesn't bind to results).

in general, you don't need lookahead much, because you can just match.  it's used mainly when you want to match a group, but for some (strange) reason need to check a specific case beforehand.

[edit:] if you just want to capture the two words then use `([_a-z0-9]+)(?:\.|->)([_a-z0-9]+)` (note that will capture two groups, one for each word).

[edit2:] if this is for a syntax highlighter then i think you could go with something that highlights *either* word.  it's easier to show than explain:

```
(?:[_a-z0-9]+(?=(?:\.|->)[_a-z0-9]+)|(?<=[_a-z0-9]+(?:\.|->))[_a-z0-9]+)
```

that will highlight either "a word followed by .word" or "a word preceded by word.", which will highlight both words without highlighting the dot.  they are two separate matches, but the syntax highlighter doesn't care about that (i assume).

Comment: I used `[_a-z0-9]+(?:\.|->)[_a-z0-9]+` but it matches `hints6.ai_flags` when I only want `hints6` and `ai_flags`

Comment: Is it possible to do it without grouping ? The regex I am using does not provide a method to call groups; that is why I was trying to use an alternative method.

Comment: not that i know of.  see lack of replies at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002218/regex-exclude-sub-group-text-from-being-included-in-a-parent-sub-group

Comment: @kikumbob i think you meant to ask RichardIlos

Comment: @kikumbob I am editing my syntax-highlighter in Gedit (gtksourceview). Apparently, the config file does not support selecting only groups recursively when highlighting: /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/c.lang

Comment: I posted a question about this yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592805/gedit-syntax-highlighting-with-gtksourceview-for-backreferencing-sub-patterns

Comment: that's a different issue.  the above (edit 2) will work for the details in this question, but if "hints6" appears alone, elsewhere, then it won't be highlighted.  that's just a basic limitation of the highlighting (according to that question's answer).